# is there command to disable to import data for power bi?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Is there a command that doesn't import the data? This is because I want to make old pbix file unusable after releasing a new pbix file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Power Query Editor right click on query name (table name) then uncheck the “Include In Report Refresh”. Do for each query name (table name).